# Generic Swift function to test for object type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types

I'm trying to write a function that takes an object and a type as arguments and returns a boolean indicating whether or not the object is of the given type. There doesn't seem to be a Type type, so I'm not sure how to do this. The best I've been able to do is

```
func objectIsType<T>(object: AnyObject, someObjectOfType: T) -> Bool {
    return object is T
}
```

So I can do `objectIsType(x, 5)`, to test if `x` is an `Int` or `objectIsType(x, "hi")` to see if it's a string, but I'd like to be able to call `objectIsType(x, Int)` to see if `x` is an `Int` and  `objectIsType(x, String)` to see if it's a `String`. Is something like this possible?

Edit:

Airspeed Velocity improved my function and made a great point about it doing exactly what `is` already does. The new function is this:

```
func objectIsType<T>(object: Any, someObjectOfType: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return object is T
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to validate that the values of a `[String: Any]` dictionary are of the type that I expect. For instance:

```
let validator: [String: Any.Type] = [
    "gimme an int": Int.self,
    "this better be a string": String.self
]

let validatee: [String: Any] = [
    "gimme an int": 3,
    "this better be a string": "it is!"
]

for (key, type) in validator {
    if !objectIsType(validatee[key], type) {
        selfDestruct()
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error, `<>protocol.Type is not convertible to T.type`. I've looked at the Metatype documentation, but I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: Using `AnyObject` is dangerous here.  `x` will get converted from an `Int` to an `NSNumber` so `objectIsType(5 as Int, 5 as Double) == true`

Comment: Maybe, you should post your edit as another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to supply a type as the argument, not a value, you can do the following:

```
func objectIsType<T>(object: Any, someObjectOfType: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return object is T
}

let a: Any = 1

objectIsType(a, Int.self)  // returns true
```

NB, `AnyObject` can only refer to classes, not structs or enums.  `Int` and `String` are structs.  If you change your code, as I have above, to take an `Any`, it works with structs too.

It might have seemed like your original worked without this change, but really what was happening was the interop was converting your `Int` into an `NSNumber` which is a bit of a roundabout way of doing things and won't adapt to the metatype-based approach.

But the question really is, why do you think you need this?  `is` already does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks @Airspeed! Would love to hear any thoughts on my edit.