# Type checking and validation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, types

I initially posted this question as followup edit of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015185/generic-swift-function-to-test-for-object-type), but it seems sufficiently separate to stand as its own question. So here it is.

I'm trying validate that the values of a `[String: Any]` dictionary are of the type that I expect. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
func objectIsType<T>(object: Any, someObjectOfType: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return object is T
}


let validator: [String: Any.Type] = [
    "gimme an int": Int.self,
    "this better be a string": String.self
]

let validatee: [String: Any] = [
    "gimme an int": 3,
    "this better be a string": "it is!"
]

for (key, type) in validator {
    if !objectIsType(validatee[key], type) {
        selfDestruct()
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error, `<>protocol.Type is not convertible to T.type.`  If, instead of using the `objectIsType` function, I just use `is` directly, making the loop

```
for (key, type) in validator {
    if !(validatee[key] is type) {
        selfDestruct()
    }
}
```

I get the error, `'type' is not a type`. I've looked at the Swift Metatype documentation, but I'm still a bit confused. Is there a good way to do this type of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach isn’t going to work I’m afraid.  The reason being, you are trying to mix dynamic run-time behaviour with static compile-time checks.

The function:

```
func objectIsType<T>(object: Any, someObjectOfType: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return object is T
}
```

is using a kind of a hack/trick to do something that Swift doesn’t like doing, which is specifying the type for a generic placeholder without context.  What does that mean?  Well, really, what you wanted to do is this:

```
func objectIsType<T>(obj: Any) -> Book { return obj is T }
```

and then call it like this:

```
// See if myAny is an Integer...
objectIsType<Int>(myAny)
```

But in Swift (unlike in, say, C++), you can’t do this.  You can’t tell the compiler “use `Int` for the placeholder `T`”.  Swift will only let you determine `T` from the context you’re calling it in.  So instead, the trick you use is to fix `T` by some other means.  Here, you’re using the type’s metatype.  An alternative would be to supply a dummy value that isn’t used (like in your original question).

```
func objectIsType<T>(object: Any, dummyValOfThatType: T) -> Bool {
    // no use of the dummy value is made...
    return object is T
}

// then, to detect Ints, supply a dummy Int
objectIsType(myAny, 1)
```

Obviously magicking up dummy values is a bit rubbish, hence the metatype solution feels better.  But unfortunately, it’s given the illusion that there is a variable out there that can be used to refer to a run-time type, and can then be used with `is` or `as`.  But this is just that, an illusion.  You cannot do this with Swift’s basic types.  They just don’t support it.

Bear in mind what happens when you call a generic function is that *at compile time*, Swift writes you a version of the function that you need for the type you are using it with.  So when you supply an `Int.self`, what actually happens is the compiler writes you this function:

```
objectIsType(obj: Any, someObjectOfType: Int.Type) -> Bool {
    return obj is Int
}
```

I can’t stress this enough, it does this *at compile time*.  So there is no way that this function can be called with a variety of different types determined at runtime and have it work.  Instead, when you declare your dictionaries, you are declaring a dictionary full of values of `Any.Type`.  Since `Any.Type` is a super type of all other types, you can still assign `String.Type` to it, but really all you’ll be storing is `Any.Type`.  The `protocol<>.Type` is actually another way of saying `Any.Type` because that’s what `Any` is: it’s defined as `typealias Any = protocol<>`.  Even if you did get your code to compile, it would always return true as what you’re asking is if `objectIsType(Any, Any.Type)`

(I’m not quite sure why it won’t, other than that you need to unwrap the value you’re getting out of the dictionary since it’s optional, but this ought to do it: `if let obj = validatee[key] where !objectIsType(obj, type.self) { selfDestruct() }` )

Basically, if you want this kind of runtime dynamic type behaviour, you’re probably going to have to stick with `@objc` land, unless someone else out there knows a good trick.

*However*, this is the point where I ask: what are you actually trying to achieve?  Do you really need this kind of dynamic behaviour?  Quite often, you can rephrase your actual goal in terms of compile-time generics instead of mucking around with converting `Any`.  Not always, but often.